# Android: jUnit Test Android Library

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, junit

I am trying to test a library developed by me through jUnit, but I'm having some problems. This library requires an activity to be instantiated. However, following the  tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html), I can not instantiate the object because I dont have the activity. You can create a dummy activity?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have activity (or want to create a dummy activity) in your library project? What does your library project actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test an `Activity` you should normally use [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html). When you invoke `getActivity()` the `Activity` under test will be created.

If you are testing a library project, the post [android: testing library project](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-testing-library-projects.html) would be also of help.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing Android applications is tricky because of the stubbed out API implementation ("java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!")

If you want to unit test your Android Activities and such, [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) is a nice option:  http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/